# Get product_cat of products in cart page woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

As the title says, what is the best way to get the product category of the products which are contained in the cart page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get cart contents with `WC()->cart->get_cart()`
2. Get product id with loop `$content['product_id']`
3. Get product terms with `get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat')`
4. Get the name of the term with a loop `$term->name`

Comment: i tried your code but it inside  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { } my record is not printing can you help ...???